# Why doesn't Visual Studio Code recognize my WSL bash python?

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running Visual Studio Code on Windows 10 with WSL bash as its terminal:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:/Windows/sysnative/bash.exe"
```

In WSL bash I have both `python` (v2.7) and `python3` (v3.6) installed.

I have installed the Python extension for VS Code. Unfortunately VS Code fails to recognize either version of Python in WSL bash.

For example when I try to discover tests, I get the following error in the Python Test Log output window:

> Test Discovery failed:
>
> Error: spawn python ENOENT

**How can I configure VS Code to work with Python form WSL bash?**

Note: I'm pretty sure I need to configure a path to Python in the `"python.pythonPath"` key in VS Code's user settings file. I am unsure of which path to put as the value though.

Comment: Quibble re: "bash as its terminal" -- bash isn't a terminal, it's a shell. A terminal does the work of displaying a window, and transmits textual data to or from programs whose output is displayed in that window. Bash itself doesn't know *anything* about windowing systems, graphics, &c; it's not a terminal at all, purely a shell.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to stick with VS Code terminology :)

Comment: Gotcha. UNIX terminology is a bit different, so this question crosses worlds a bit -- probably for the better that there wasn't need to say either "directory" or "folder" to avoid any holy wars on that topic from drifting in either. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Support for WSL is done through the "WSL - Remote" extension. There is a [WSL blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/an-in-depth-tutorial-on-linux-development-on-windows-with-wsl-and-visual-studio-code/) which covers how to get started.

Comment: It seems that this is supported now?  So a better answer would be how to do this now.

Comment: @JackStrosahl thanks for noticing that the answer was outdated! I've now updated it.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  I was asking because I was trying to do it.  Essentially all I was missing was that extension.